# DatePicker not working correctly on sharepoint 2013 subsites

Tags: 2013

I am having the following issue on date fields on subsites. the weird thing is that in root site the date picker just works fine.

These date fields are provisioned with xml site columns, there is nothing special on them

[image: http://screencast.com/t/tUIWGw6b]

```
  <Field
       ID="{99E2FB9E-4DBD-4BCA-B1DE-7016C814D966}"
       Name="xxx_ApprovalDate"
       StaticName="xxx_ApprovalDate"
       DisplayName="$Resources:xxx,sitecolumns_client_approvalDate_displayName;"
       Type="DateTime"
       Format="DateOnly"
       Required="FALSE"
       Group="$Resources:xxx,sitecolumns_fieldgroup;">
    <Default>[today]</Default>
  </Field>
```

EDIT:

I think I have nailed it down to be a problem in the custom master page, our custom master page is a copy of seattle.master, however with a small jquery script to render the navigation menu on a separate search center

I guess this script is causing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if ($('.ms-searchCenter-refinement').length > 0) {
                // Unhide the title row
                $('#s4-titlerow').attr('style', 'display:block !important');
                // Set the Site Title
                $('#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea').text('Search Center');
                // Hide the search icon
                $('#searchIcon').hide();
                // Remove the top margin 
                $('.ms-searchCenter-refinement').css('margin-top', '0');

                // The following line is only needed for firefox
                $('body').append('<style>#s4-titlerow { display: block !important; }</style');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Is it working on other pages? Seems to me that this form has some custom styling and scripting that could mess with the datepicker

Comment: just checked its not working on other pages, the date picker is rendered via an iframe, I wonder if my custom styling broke the calendar, or maybe it was a custom js file or something, but its hard to debug

Comment: I think i have this same problem, the difference its that its on standard site columns, not user controls or custom app pages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243408/sharepoint-2010-datetimecontrol-styling-issues

Comment: Did this ever get answered? I am having the same problem.

Comment: This isn't the problem, just noting the firefox body.append line is missing its closing > on the closing style tag. Wasn't sure if it was a copy/paste error or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I noticed the following strange behavior:

The masterpage is provisioned via a module, but it was not GhostableInLibrary, after I put this property then the problem of the calendar is gone.

Comment: Hi Could you please provide the steps how you did this "GhostableInLibrary". I am having a similar issue. Your earliest response would be much appreciated. Thanks,
Deepa

Answer (score 0):

You can add master page as GhostableInLibrary, using Element file of master page solution

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
     <module name="MasterPagesModule" url="_catalogs/masterpage"  rootwebonly="True" path="">
     <file url="MySharePointe.master" ignoreifalreadyexists="TRUE"   type="GhostableInLibrary"></file>
     <file url="Contoso.master" ignoreifalreadyexists="TRUE" type="GhostableInLibrary"></file>
   </module>
    </element>
```